# shiny: multiple conditional panels within main panel is not working

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to code an application for linear and multiple regression using shiny, I have an issue with multiple conditional panels,

that,

- It does not check for conditions and executes first conditional panel.
- That's not a single problem, it also fails to read the file and remains as it is for the first condition panel which is selected.

  ```
  library(shiny)    
  # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    ui <- fluidPage(

   # # Application title
   # column(9,
   #   titlePanel("Multiple Regression")
   #   
   #   ),


   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("sel_type",
                     "Select Regression Type ",
                     c("Linear Regression"="LR","Multiple Regression"="MR"),
                     selected = "LR"),
         fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                   accept = c(
                     "text/csv",
                     "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                     ".csv")
         ),
         uiOutput("select_predict"),
         conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.sel_type=='LR'",
           uiOutput("select_test")  
         )

      ),

      mainPanel(
         conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.sel_type=='LR'",
           h1("Simple Linear Regression"),
           br(),
           h3(textOutput("scat_plot"))
            ,plotOutput("scatter_plot",width = 500, height = 500),
           br(),
           # verbatimTextOutput("dataSet"),
           h3("Data Set"),
           br(),
           column(4,
                  h4("Test variable"),
                  tableOutput("tbl1"),
                  offset = 1
           ),
           h4("Predicting variable"),
           tableOutput("tbl"),
           br(),
           h3("correlation analysis"),
           verbatimTextOutput("cor"),
           br(),
           h3("Linear model and Regression Analysis"),
           br(),
           verbatimTextOutput("lm_ra"),
           br(),
           uiOutput("predict"),
           br(),
           verbatimTextOutput("predicted_value")
           ),

         conditionalPanel(
           condition = "input.sel_type == 'MR' ",
            h1("Multiple Regression"),
            br(),
           verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
            h2("COrrelation Analysis"),          
            br(),
            verbatimTextOutput("cor")
         )
      )
   )
  )

  # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
    server <- function(input, output) {

  # sample1 <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)

  output$select_predict = renderUI({
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    selectInput("sel_test_var","Select Test variable",choices =  names(df))
  })

  output$select_test = renderUI({
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    selectInput("ip2","Select Predicting Variable",names(df)[!names(df)==input$sel_test_var])#,multiple = T)

  })

  output$scat_plot = renderText({
    sprintf(
      "Scatter plot between '%s' and '%s'", input$sel_test_var, input$ip2
    )

  })
  output$scatter_plot = renderPlot({
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    x<- df[,input$sel_test_var]
    y<- df[,input$ip2]

   if (!is.null(y)) {
    plot(x,y,xlab=input$sel_test_var, ylab=input$ip2)
    abline(lm(y~x))
    }
      })
  # output$dataSet = renderPrint({
  #   df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  #   sprintf("Data of %s",input$sel_test_var)
  #   df[,input$sel_test_var]
  # #  sprintf("Data of %s",input$ip2)
  #  #   df[,input$ip2]
  # })


  output$tbl = renderTable({
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    z <- as.data.frame(df[,input$ip2])
    names(z) <- input$ip2
    z
  })
  output$tbl1 = renderTable({
    df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    z <- as.data.frame(df[,input$sel_test_var])
    names(z) <- input$sel_test_var
    z
  })
   output$cor=renderPrint({
   df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
   result <- cor.test(df[,input$ip2],df[,input$sel_test_var],method = "pearson")
   result
   }) 
   output$lm_ra = renderPrint({
   df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
   model1 <- lm(df[,input$sel_test_var] ~ df[,input$ip2])
   model1
   #sprintf("Summury linear model")
   cat(sprintf("Model summary"))
   summary(model1)
   })

      output$predict = renderUI({

     numericInput(inputId = "predict_value",label = "Enter Predicting value",value = 10)
   })

   output$predicted_value = renderPrint({
   df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
   x <- df[,input$ip2]
   model1 <- lm(df[,input$sel_test_var] ~ x)
   y=predict(model1,data.frame(x = input$predict_value),interval = "confidence", level=0.95)
   y
   })

   ########################## Multiple Regression #################################

   output$summary = renderPrint({
   df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
   cat(paste("Structure of Data Set\n"))
      str(df)
   #cat(paste("\n\n"))
   # cat(paste("Dimension of Data Set\n"))
   #  dim(df)
    cat(paste("\n\n"))
   cat(paste("Summary of Data Set\n"))
    summary(df)
   })

   output$cor = renderPrint({
   df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
   cor(df)
   })

  }




  # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  ```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Can you share your server code and the data that you are using?

Comment: yep i've added server code that now you can review it, thanks!!!

Comment: Can you share the data that you are using? Or a sample dataset which is similar to the data that you'll upload in your app? This is because having the data makes it much easier to reproduce your problem and look into it.

Comment: I'm using data similar to built-in dataset "trees", where it contains three fields "height", "girth" and "width".

Comment: i got an error, thanks Vishesh !!!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I've named two output variables with the same name, that is "cor". which were conflicting for linear and multiple regression panels.